# Tapping into VGA output of a PC

Tags: computer-vision, vga

Is it possible to tap into the VGA output of a (different) computer? The computer in question will be running a driving simulator (which is at full screen). I would like to feed this video to another computer running a program, that I've written, which can detect motorway/freeway lanes and generate an output to steer the vehicle running in the driving simulator.

I did find this: http://www.synthenv.com/PixelPusher_usb_frame_grabber.aspx

A Frame grabber that can a VGA input and output it as a USB. Its also compatible with OpenCV (which is what I'm using for computer vision). Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at VGA2USB Frame Grabber?

Answer (score 0):

Frame grabbers are definitely an option. You could also convert your VGA signal to S-Video and use any graphics card with TV-in. Or, if you do not insist on running this on two computers, you could use a screen-grabbing camera driver, like http://www.splitmedialabs.com/vh-video-sdk/vh-screen-capture